# Is feature selection needed before fiting ANN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection

I have 36 variables and I want to fit simple MLP with one output. Do I need to select most descriptive variables? I think it should be better to feed MLP with all variables.

I know that people are making feature selection before fitting ANN but why is it the case? Shouldn't MLP make feature selection in learning process?

Comment: What does MLP stand for?

Comment: MLP = Multi Layer Perceptron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better feature set would help you to make more concrete decisions later in the process and it also helps to remove some of the unwanted noise that is present in the dataset and features that might mislead one. That being said, having noise in the data is a good thing as it might help you generalize better.

I am guessing that you are trying to perform a supervised task, in that case, you can keep all the variables and try dropping your neurons from the perceptron at random (dropout) in order to reduce the dependency on a particular variable.

It would be better if you elaborate your question a bit, explain a bit more about the dataset and see if you really need a neural network for the task or some off the shelf model would work out for you.

Comment: You're right, I'll be doing supervised learning. I don't want to go in specific details of my project. I'm interested in general answer. My data set consist of 10'000 data points which is quite large.

Comment: I would suggest you see the correlation between the variables and your target label or value and weed out a few of them that might not be required at all. You can try dropout in conjunction with this to add some robustness to your model.

Comment: Thank you saha rudra for your input. I think you just confirmed my felling that it's not necessary to do feature selection when data set is large. I think that MLP will exclude vars (thanks to nonlinearity) which lowers the quality of ANN output.

Comment: Dropping variables at random is absolutely the wrong approach in model building, why don't you use domain knowledge to select variables  or variable clustering?

Comment: Yes @forecaster I do concur that. I am asking feature selection to be done before this and then using this as an implicit regularizer as I do not know the exact task that the person is performing and thus also asked to look into other models than just throwing data at a neural network. One can certainly perform explicit regularization.